How to make a restricted IP API work with Microsoft Fabric
My company uses a specific application for tracking of data. I now have been asked to report on this data. The application itself can only be reached via our VPN. If the VPN is not enabled, the app cannot be reached.
The application provider informed me today that also to call the API, I need to go through a whitelisted IP address or the VPN.
I have a local report on my laptop and that works fine, I can call the API and get the data. However, we want to save this data in a lakehouse in MS Fabric.
If I try to setup a dataflow gen.2 in a fabric capacity enabled workspace, I get the following error:

Unable to create connection for the following reason: Unable to connect to the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection timeout occurred, or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.

I have tried to setup the connection in a dataflow and in the connections and gateway manager page, in both cases I get the error.
I know the credentials are correct.
What can I do to fix this?

You need to add the Azure data centre IP ranges to the app whitelist.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

one solution is to set-up a PBI gateway on a server, authorize the IP of this server, and connect to the API using the gateway.
